# Ubuntu 14.10 LTS with new skylake processors .

Tags: intel

I am looking to get a new workstation with a intel i5 or i7 skylake . Can I use ubuntu on this without problems . I don't really want to mess about installing kernels. I am not that much of an expert . Please help .

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 is not supported for a long time and this question is off-topic here. You'd better tried to ask it at ubuntuforums.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) Intel processors and Ubuntu go together like ice cream and ice cream cones.

Comment: You will probably want to run 16.04 to get the best experience with Skylake.

Answer (score 1):

I have installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.0.4.3 LTS on my new HP Envy machine which has quad core i7(skylake) working fine without any issues. Please give it a try.

This is my laptop configuration on which i have installed Ubuntu Desktop 14.04.3 LTS alongside Windows 10. I had just upgrade to Kernel 4.2.5 as wifi(Intel AC 3165) was not supported. And also get nvidia graphics driver from ppa. Everything else is OOTB Ubuntu installation. Working fine.

> Product specifications Operating system Windows 10 Pro 64
>
> Processor and graphics 6th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-6700HQ Quad Core
>   Processor + NVIDIA GeForce GTX 950M 4GB Discrete Graphics
>
> Display
>   15.6-inch diagonal Full HD WLED-backlit IPS Display (1920x1080)
>
> Memory 16GB DDR3L System Memory (2 Dimm)
>
> Hard drive 512 GB SSD Eluktronics
>
> Office software Office Software Trial
>
> Primary battery 6-cell 62WHr Lithium-ion Battery
>
> Keyboard Backlit Keyboard
>
> Personalization HP TrueVision HD Webcam with Dual Digital Microphone
>
> Networking Intel 802.11ac WLAN and Bluetooth(R) [1x1] Battery life Up
>   to 5 hours and 30 minutes
>
> Audio Bang & Olufsen with 2 speakers and 1 subwoofer
>
> Pointing device HP Imagepad with multi-touch gesture support
>
> Memory slots 2 user-accessible
>
> Network interface Integrated 10/100/1000 Gigabit Ethernet LAN
>
> Expansion slots 1 multi-format SD media card reader
>
> External I/O Ports 2 USB 3.0 (1 HP USB Boost); 2 USB 2.0; 1 HDMI; 1
>   RJ-45; 1 headphone/microphone combo
>
> Power supply 120 W AC power adapter
>
> Energy efficiency ENERGY STAR® certified; EPEAT® Silver registered
>   Dimensions (W X D X H)
>   14.94 x 9.87 x 1.1 in
>
> Weight
>   5.06 lb
>
> Warranty 1-year limited hardware warranty, toll-free support
>
> Software included McAfee LiveSafe™ 30-day trial offer (Internet access
>   required. First 30 days included. Subscription required for live
>   updates afterwards.)
>
> Model number 15t-q400